# Running SQL Through an ODBC with no SQL Server Licence

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I am looking to write SQL for my new role but have zero tech support and am out on my own here, I have an understanding of how to write SQL, that's not the issue. In my last role I used Teradata daily but in my new position the company has never done anything with big data management via SQL therefore has no server or server licence.

All of our data is housed through a 3rd party called Netsuite and we have an ODBC connection to the data tables. The issue is, I have no way to write SQL against the tables in a user friendly way outside of MS Access or MS Queries  (not the most user friendly interface to write SQL). Is there any interface that does not require a local server that will let me connect via an ODBC and write SQL/see the tables inner join and all that fun stuff?

I have tried MS SSMS but cannot connect to the ODBC until I set up a local connection, and I don't have a local server or licence.

Comment: Please be more explicit, what do you mean when you say you don't have a friendly way to write SQL against tables outside MS access

Comment: SSMS does not require a local connection.

Comment: Oscar- All I have is the ODBC driver, no other programs installed to write SQL outside of MS office programs.

Horse with no name- In SSMS in the walk throughs that I have found the first step is to connect locally and then you are able to connect to the ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple tools that might work for you:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/odbcquerytool/

http://download.cnet.com/SQL-Query-Tool-Using-ODBC/3000-10254_4-10057486.html